# How to make γ-MnO2 in a lab?

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, ionic-compounds, transition-metals

I am working on Li-ion batteries, and I need to use γ-$\ce{MnO2}$ (electrolytic manganese dioxide). I have googled and read quite a few papers, but I am not very sure of those methods. I'd love to know if you are aware of some! The ones which I encountered, again and again, was the one involving precipitation of $\ce{MnO2}$. But is it possible to precipitate the γ form? Also, I think the commercially available $\ce{MnO2}$ is the α form. Is there any way to convert it to γ form? **I am particularly looking for a way to synthesize  $\ce{MnO2}$ using electrolysis.**

I know that I can also break a few batteries to get my $\ce{MnO2}$, but it would be heavily contaminated by carbon. Commercially available  $\ce{MnO2}$ is very expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search yields [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese_dioxide#Electrolytic_manganese_dioxide)

> [Electrolytic manganese dioxide] is produced in a similar fashion as
>   electrolytic tough pitch (ETP) copper: The manganese dioxide is
>   dissolved in sulfuric acid (sometimes mixed with manganese sulfate)
>   and subjected to a current between two electrodes. The $\ce{MnO2}$ dissolves,
>   enters solution as the sulfate, and is deposited on the anode.

Unfortunately, there is no source for the information.

Some further searching yields [this](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2015/ra/c5ra05892a#!divAbstract) article, with the following information:

> EMD ($\gamma$-$\ce{MnO2}$) can be prepared from the direct electrolysis
>   of an aqueous bath of manganese sulfate and sulphuric acid. The
>   electrochemical deposition of $\ce{MnO2}$ on an inert electrode from
>   an electrolyte containing $\ce{Mn^2+}$ occurs as per the reaction
>   noted below:
>
> $\begin{alignat*}{3}&\textrm{anode: }\quad&&\ce{Mn^2+ + 2H2O} &&\ce{->
> MnO2 + 4H+ + 2e-} \\ &\textrm{cathode: } \quad&&\ce{2H+ + 2e-}
> &&\ce{->H2} \end{alignat*}$

Note that the linked article is a review, with a lot of information, both about the actual structure of $\gamma$-$\ce{MnO2}$ as well as the reactions that lead to the production of the correct crystalline structure in the presence of acid. There are a number of references that you may find useful as well.

Comment: Did you find what you needed?

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up; that's very kind of you! I have made three samples and will be sending them for XRD tomorrow. I hope they are $\gamma$!